# Probability in Rolling dice 6 times

Tags: probability, dice

If I have one die and I'm rolling the dice $6$ times.
What is the probability that in the all $6$ times the result will be the same?

I know that the probability for each number in $6$ sides dice is $\frac{1}{6}$

If I want the result to be 2 in all times, the probability is $(\frac{1}{6})^6$, right?

So for the $6$ numbers not needing to be $6 * (\frac{1}{6})^6$, is it right?

The other issue is, what is the probabilty that in $2$ of the $6$ rolling, 
it gets the same result?

Comment: Your answer to the first question is correct. For the second question, try finding the probability of that not happening.

Comment: please explain more... 112345 is for sure acceptable. Is 111234 acceptable? Is 112234 acceptable?

Comment: @IBWiglin thanks, can you explain more? I think that there is a formulat but I don't remember.. it's been a while since I deald with probability :)

Comment: @ThanosDarkadakis, the question says that the result was the same in 2 flips, and I need to find the probability of that.

Comment: The second part needs the words "at least" or "exactly" before "2 of the 6 rolling" to avoid misunderstanding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first roll there are no restrictions. For the second, you have 5 choices. For the third, 4 and so forth. Hence, the probability of it not happening is $1\cdot \frac{5}{6}\cdot \frac{4}{6}\cdot ...\cdot \frac{1}{6} = \frac{5!}{6^{5}}$. Hence, the probability of it happening is $1 - \frac{5!}{6^{5}} = \frac{6^{5} - 5!}{6^{5}}$.

Comment: RIGHT ! thanks! 
can you please tell me if my answer to the first question is right?

Comment: Yes, it definitely is.

Comment: This answer is correct for "at least one duplicate roll"  Is that the same as "in 2 of the 6 rolling, it gets the same result"?